# Implicit type conversion for bitwise operation

Tags: c++, type-conversion, bitwise-operators

I have this operation:

```cpp
uint32_t DIM = // ...
int32_t x = // ...

// Operation:
x & (DIM-1u)
```

How does implicit type conversion work in the statement `x & (DIM-1u)`?

- Does it convert `x` to `uint32_t`?
- Or `(DIM-1u)` to `int32_t`?
- Also, what would be the result type? Is it `uint32_t` or `int32_t`

Comment: Rules can be found here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two scenarios, noting that `1u` is a literal of type `unsigned`:

1. `unsigned` is in the inclusive range of 16 bits to 31 bits. The type of `DIM - 1u` is `uint32_t`, and the whole expression is `uint32_t`. This is because the `signed` type in a binary expression where the other argument is an `unsigned` type is converted implicitly to `unsigned`.
2. `unsigned` is 32 bits or larger. Then the type of `DIM - 1u` is `unsigned`, and the same for the type of the whole expression.

---

Finally, note that the C++ standard permits `unsigned` and `std::uint32_t` to be the same type; i.e.

```
std::cout << std::is_same<std::uint32_t, unsigned>::value;
```

is allowed to be 1.